# Filter out oidc correlation failed exceptions from App Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a .net core 2.2 web app with OpenID Connect login and a baseline App Insights installation.  I am able to generate an error by waiting 15 minutes on the login page and then submitting.  However, I don't want these to show up in app insights as we have alerts based on number of errors.  How can these errors from "signin-oidc" be filtered out either by preventing the application from sending it or having app insights ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ITelemetryProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#filtering-itelemetryprocessor) to abandon the unwanted messages.

First of all, you need to use visual studio to check the unique properties of the errors(from "signin-oidc"), like below(it's a trace message for example):

[image]

Then create a custom class which implements the ITelemetryProcessor. Remember that use the unique property or property combination to filter out the unwanted messages. Code like below:

```
namespace WebApplication1netcore4
{
    public class MyTelemetryProcessor : ITelemetryProcessor
    {
        private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

        public MyTelemetryProcessor(ITelemetryProcessor next)
        {
            this.Next = next;
        }

        public void Process(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {

            ExceptionTelemetry err1= telemetry as ExceptionTelemetry;

            // you can also use combinations of properties by using && or || operator
            if (err1!= null && err1.Context.Properties.Keys.Contains("the unique property of that error"))
            {

                if (err1.Context.Properties["unique property"] == "the property value")
                {
                    //return means abandon this error message which has the specified property value
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (err1 == null)
            {
                this.Next.Process(telemetry);

            }

            if (err1 != null)
            {
                this.Next.Process(err1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices() method, add the following code:

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<MyTelemetryProcessor>();
```